# Request editor doesnt open for some request after save close and open project in SOAP UI

Tags: soapui

This is weird, I am using SOAP UI 5.0 free ware, after I save project close and reopen it; I am unable to open the Request editor for some requests in the project, In fact all the test steps it is associated fails and is not opening. There is no error as well.
I had saved the project as xml and when I imported it as well same issue for the same request. 
Is there something wrong I am doing. Please help rework is a pain.

[image]

Comment: What is in the error tab? What is in `$SOAPUI_HOME\bin\soapui-errors.log`? Need [mcve] or we cannot help you!

Comment: Hi SiKing, Find below the error text attached from the log file.

Comment: I am not sure if you can open the attachement. But just copying the first few lines of the error:   2016-03-23 18:51:05,245 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.support.RestRequestParamsPropertyHolder.getPropertyAt(RestRequestParamsPropertyHolder.java:239)

Comment: Found The solution: http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/Resolved-SoapUI-4-6-4-open-rest-request-editor-error/td-p/38708

Answer (score 1):

Found The solution on smart bear community site: 
http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/Resolved-SoapUI-4-6-4-open-rest-request-editor-error/td-p/38708

"The issue was that, for some reasons there were some duplicate & blank properties listed in the resource params tab for the resource that contained this rest request(in 4.6.4). When I cleared those out and re-keyed them again, I was able to get them to work as expected."

Comment: It's also useful to restart SoapUI after that (especially if some empty properties can't be deleted, as it was in my case).